# Foundation background color issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I developed the FE of my application with Zurb Foundation CSS. Although everything seemed to work fine, I noticed that the background color of my application is not visible on vertical scroll. Here is a screenshot 
 [image]

I tried to fix the issue by changing

```
 body{
     height:100%;
 }
```

to

```
 body{
      min-height:100%;
  }
```

it solved this issue, but caused the background to wrap around the lesser content on the Home page.

Comment: Your link will not let me see the page. It asks for a sign up.

Comment: Oh sorry, removed the link. How ever I guess that the image sums it up.

Comment: my best assumption (since the link was removed) is that it's an overflow issue where your container is wrapping around your content properly, hence why the body is only rendering partially. Go into Inspect element and see if you can find which container the overflow is stopping short on, post a live or possibly a JSFiddle?

Comment: Without the code it is very difficult to troubleshoot but what you can try to do is wrap both of your sections, the table, and the part with show list in divs with a "row"  I experienced this issue on one project and that resolved it for me.